# Laravel 4: Is there any extension of multiple captcha in one page?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have used mews/captcha plugin in my project. 
But the problem is i am not able to add multiple captcha in same page.

Thanks & regards,
Monang Shah

Comment: This seems more like an design/user experience issue. A single captcha is enough to prove the user isn't a bot.

Comment: I agree with Andre... you should figure out first why you even need more than one captcha.

Comment: I have three forms on the same page and need to protect from spamming

Comment: You can use this package for google recaptcha greggilbert/recaptcha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using mews/captcha, I have use custom captcha for the same. Please find the code below:-

Controller Function:-

```
public function get_captcha($id, $width = 120, $height = 30) {      
        $config = array(
            'fontsizes' => array(14, 15, 16, 17, 18),
            'length' => 5,
            'width' => $width,
            'height' => $height,
            'space' => 20,
            'colors' => array('128,23,23', '128,23,22', '33,67,87', '67,70,83', '31,56,163', '48,109,22', '165,42,166', '18,95,98', '213,99,8'),
            'sensitive' => false, // case sensitive (params: true, false)
            'quality' => 80 // image quality
        );

        $fonts = $backgrounds = array();
        $assets = __DIR__ . '/../../../captcha/';
        foreach (glob($assets . '*.ttf') as $filename) {
            $fonts[] = $filename;
        }
        foreach (glob($assets . '*.png') as $filename) {
            $backgrounds[] = $filename;
        }

        $char = Str::random($config['length']);

        Session::put('captchaHash'.$id, ($config['sensitive'] === true ? $char : Str::lower($char)));

        $bg_image = $backgrounds[rand(0, count($backgrounds) - 1)];

        $bg_image_info = getimagesize($bg_image);
        if ($bg_image_info['mime'] == 'image/jpg' || $bg_image_info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg')
        {
            $old_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($bg_image);
        }
        elseif ($bg_image_info['mime'] == 'image/gif')
        {
            $old_image = imagecreatefromgif($bg_image);
        }
        elseif ($bg_image_info['mime'] == 'image/png')
        {
            $old_image = imagecreatefrompng($bg_image);
        }

        $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($config['width'], $config['height']);
        $bg = imagecolorallocate($new_image, 255, 255, 255);
        imagefill($new_image, 0, 0, $bg);

        imagecopyresampled($new_image, $old_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $config['width'], $config['height'], $bg_image_info[0], $bg_image_info[1]);

        $bg = imagecolorallocate($new_image, 255, 255, 255);
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($char); $i++)
        {
            $color_cols = explode(',', $config['colors'][rand(0, count($config['colors']) - 1)]);
            $fg = imagecolorallocate($new_image, trim($color_cols[0]), trim($color_cols[1]), trim($color_cols[2]));
            imagettftext($new_image, $config['fontsizes'][rand(0, count($config['fontsizes']) - 1)], rand(-10, 15), 10 + ($i * $config['space']), rand($config['height'] - 10, $config['height'] - 5), $fg, $fonts[rand(0, count($fonts) - 1)], $char[$i]);
        }
        imagealphablending($new_image, false);

        header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: no-cache');
        header("Content-type: image/jpg");
        header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=' . $id . '.jpg');
        imagejpeg($new_image, null, $config['quality']);
        imagedestroy($new_image);
    }
```

I have call captcha image into view using

```
{{ Form::image(SITE_URL."get-captcha/captcha1?".time(),'Captcha image',array('id'=>'captcha1')) }}
```

**NOTE:** captchaHash is generated dynamically for each captcha. You can download captcha zip //103.8.216.142/projects/captcha.zip into browser

Thanks, Monang